# Host git repository and access it through my computer's ip

Tags: git, version-control, github, host

I would like to host my project on my own computer, since my computer is on all the time, and access it when im away from home and clone it on my other laptop when needed, and then commit to my desktop computer, basically using it as a GIT host.

Is it possible to do so? I do not want to use GitHub since I dont want to pay the $7 a month, and i would like to use my computer instead.

I made a repository right now with all of my project files inside, how do i continue from here?

Comment: Use bitbucket.com it's free for up to 5 people teams.

Comment: bitbucket is best for private repos. Free and unlimited repos. You still can use github for opensource projects.

Comment: There is also GitLab, which has a free cloud-based option. The nice thing about GitLab is that if you want to run the same software yourself later, you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use [Atlassian BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org), which has unlimited free private repos

Comment: Thanks! i will look into it, looks just like what i was looking for!